# Display large String from JTextField in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I would like to transfer a large `String` from a `JTextField` to a `JLabel`,but it is not displaying as expected

E.g:

> wwwwxxyy...

As upon reaching the end of the `JLabel` it stops, but i would like it to continue to the next line

Please guide me

My code:

```
String url=txturl.getText();
String uname = txuser.getText();
String pwd = pass.getText();
pass.setVisible(false);
txuser.setVisible(false);
txturl.setVisible(false);
JLabel path=new JLabel();
JLabel username=new JLabel();
JLabel password=new JLabel();
path.setText("path is:"+url.toString());
username.setText("usename is:"+uname);
password.setText("password is:"+pwd);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Judging from the uncompilabel code snippets seen above, though, I'd suggest to use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556), to change the view of the container.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a lot of text, then a `JLabel` is not the best choice. A suitable alternative would be a [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) due to the word wrapping capabilities

For example, using [Lorem Ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) as the text to display and the text area set to wrap text with: `textArea.setLineWrap(true);` you can see the benefits:

[image: JLabel vs JTextArea]

(Include `textArea.setEditable(false);` if you don't want the contents to be modifiable by the user)

For more information see: [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

---

Another point to note is that judging by this line: `String pwd = pass.getText();`, you are not using a `JPasswordField` as [`getText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText()) is deprecated. If you are then consider switching to [`getPassword()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword())

If not, you should consider the benefits of using a `JPasswordField` and reading up on how to use them here: [How to Use Password Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html)

A key benefit being that the password isn't visible during typing:

[image: JTextField vs JPasswordField]